# Connection between Gram matrix and Riemannian invariants?

Tags: reference-request, linear-algebra, riemannian-geometry

Recall that the Gram matrix of vectors $v_1, \dots, v_k\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is the $k\times k$ matrix $G_{ij}=(v_i,v_j)$. Now suppose that the vectors $v_i$ have been sampled uniformly from some submanifold $M\subset\mathbb{R}^n$. Is there some sensible notion of the limiting Gram matrix (as $k\to\infty$) in terms of the geometry of M? Maybe the largest eigenvalue converges to some Riemannian invariant of M? Any references on these kinds of questions would be appreciated!

Comment: Is $M$ compact?

Comment: Yes, I would be interested in results for either compact or non-compact M.

Comment: When you say *limiting* do you refer to what limit?

Comment: I mean in the limit as $k\to\infty$. I've edited the post now.

Comment: a discrete version of Laplacian related to $v_i$s (which can be constructed from the Gram matrix) converges pointwise to the Laplace-Beltrami operator on the submanifold. For example, see Theorem 1 in [this paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/7b3e/92ea6537ea985ddeffe13e80a9a3c0110f46.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

In the simplest case of vectors on the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^d,$ the off-diagonal entries of the Gram matrix will be Beta-distributed (with variance $1/d,$ see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/85916/distribution-of-scalar-products-of-two-random-unit-vectors-in-d-dimensions), so the matrix will not be the identity matrix. The eigenvalues will be the squares of the singular values of a random $d\times n$ matrix, for the distribution of which see the extensive oeuvre of Mark Rudelson and Roman Vershynin (see, for example, the [ICM paper](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~rudelson/papers/rv-ICM2010.pdf)). It's fairly clear that if your random vectors are on an ellipsoid you can recover the semi-axes (and the center), and for a product of spheres the matrix will have a block structure.

What happens for a general submanifold, I have no clue. Notice that is not even clear how to express the expectation of a diagonal entry (which is the squared norm of a random point on your manifold) in terms of "usual" differential geometric (really "integral geometric" is what you are looking for here) invariants.